# render a rails partial in a temporary marker in gmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails and trying to set a temporary marker (the client side) on the screen without saving it to the database, and presenting a infowindow with a rails form (server side).

I know that it is a bit tricky because I need to get the server side to give me the form at the moment of creation.
I tried the following code, but my logic in the infowindow part is wrong.

```
  function show_location(lat, lng){
    var tempmarker = {lat: lat, lng: lng, "infowindow": tempmarker.html('#{escape_javascript(render :partial => "form")}')}
    handler.addMarker(tempmarker);
     };
```

I also looked at this option on the gmaps4rails guide , but I don't think it will help me

```
Gmaps.map.jsTemplate = function(marker_container){
  //whatever you need
  return your_html;
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: do you have a map with many markers and you want to add one or the map is empty and you add the marker on the fly? BTW I dont see any call to the server in your question, could you give more details?

Comment: My map should present locations with events, but only present a location if it is associated with such event. Thus, I want to allow my user to search a location on the map, show the user a pin (temporary one) that will have a form to submit an event in it.

If the user creates an event at the temp location, it will be saved in the database, and from now on will be presented on the map from the controller

Comment: where is your ajax call here? how do you retrieve data from the server?

Comment: it should be as simple as `addMarker`

Comment: How would you add an ajax call to the "infowindow" part of the code? just "infowindow": "AJAX call as a string? "
because it seems that the infowindow just takes a string

Comment: your ajax controller should render json, simply

Comment: will you be able to point me to an example ?